# IOS 7, цвет back indicator image в нажатом состоянии

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

В iOS 7 появилась такая штука как Back Indicator Image. 
По этой ссылке на изображении видно о чем я говорю:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwOa0.jpg.
Как поменять просто цвет этой стрелочки в Normal состоянии - я знаю. Есть задача - поменять цвет этой стрелки при нажатии на нее, то есть Highlighted состояние.
Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с этим и как решил. Желательно через [UINavigationBar appearance].

Answer (score 1):

tintColor в гайде описано что юзать нужно именно его в iOS 7 для смены цвета, и возможно если Вы не будете это юзать, не пройдете апрув по дизайну. Но там категорично не запрещали, конечно, но придраться могут.
[Гайд](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1)

Comment: TintColor - это для окраски ненажатого состояния, это я уже сделал.
Мне нужно изменить цвет стрелки когда я нажимаю на нее.

Comment: Может это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940010/how-to-create-a-custom-mask-image-for-back-buttons-in-ios7
А так можно думаю по старинке setImage:forState
ну если конечно станадартные не подходят